# Ruby TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified

Tags: ruby, oracle, oci8

I have C:\ORACLE added to my ORACLE_HOME

I have C:\ORACLE and C:\ORACLE\bin in PATH

I have C:\ORACLE\network\admin in TNS_ADMIN

I am using Ruby OCI8 to connect to remote oracle server (same effect using slqplus):

```
require 'oci8'

OCI8.new(@user, @password,"#{@host}:#{@port}/#{@sid}")
```

I get this error:

```
oci8.c:557:in oci8lib_300.so: ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified (OCIError)
```

Under C:\ORACLE\network\admin I have tnsnames.ora as:

```
ORCL =
(DESCRIPTION =
(ADDRESS_LIST =
(ADDRESS = (HOST = <host>)(PORT = <port>)) )
(CONNECT_DATA =
(SID = <sid>)
)
)
```

My os is WINDOWS 10 x64.

Please help.
Thanks

Comment: You do not have to manually specify host, port and sid in case of TNS entry. Either TNS entry name or full text of the TNS entry or easy connect string with host, port and sid

Comment: @astentx. Thanks. Please provide example of easy connect

Comment: You already asked this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69485141/sqlplus-oci8-ora-12154-tnscould-not-resolve-the-connect-identifier-specif).  Starting a new thread on the same issue as your other one accomplishes nothing positive.

Comment: The documentation for ruby gem is awful... But according to [this](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/ruby-oci8/OCI8) docs in case of easy connect you should connect this way: `OCI8.new(@user, @password, "//<host>:<port>/<service_name>")`. Please note, that SID and SERVICE_NAME are different things

Comment: I'm sorry, agree with the notice above: please, move all the details to the old thread.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQLPLUS / OCI8 => ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified (OCIError)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69485141/sqlplus-oci8-ora-12154-tnscould-not-resolve-the-connect-identifier-specif)

Comment: nope unfortunately, and Ruby class instance should not give error, I completely respected the syntax.